# Must I use a parameter with the die() function in PHP?

Tags: php

I've always used the `die()` function without the 'message' parameter but the function description over at w3schools suggested the 'message' parameter is required.

Must I use the 'message' parameter when using `die()`?

For example: `die( 'Unable to do that' )`

Hoping someone can confirm the right way to use the function.

Ref: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_misc_die.asp

Comment: Use exit if you don't need a message

Comment: In PHP missing parameters are replaced by `null` - and since `null` has a printable string representation (the empty string), it is perfectly legal, while not elegant, to use `die();`

Comment: 1. step: [official manual](http://php.net/die)
2. step: see it is equivalent to [`exit`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php), which has an optional string parameter

Comment: @EugenRieck that explains it perfectly. Thank you. Would you like to post as an answer?

Comment: At @kingkero, how can the function be equiv to exit when exit doesn't require param usage? You must mean the 'outcome' is equiv?

Comment: @henrywright Working on it.

Comment: Thanks, can accept in ~6 minutes :)

Comment: @henrywright The functions are equivalent because [`die()`](http://codepad.org/KdJImJ3i) produces the same output as [`exit()`](http://codepad.org/S1E9RcWn), so do [`die("message")`](http://codepad.org/URcAKVN4) and [`exit("message")`](http://codepad.org/MsWUTDSk)

Comment: *"how can the function be equiv to exit when exit doesn't require param usage?"* - Because `die` doesn't require a parameter either. Please believe the official manual instead of some third party site with a known bad reputation.

Comment: @deceze you must believe me when I say I did consult the [official docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php) first (I always do), but nowhere did I see an explanation of whether param usage was required when using die().

Comment: Well, `die` links to `exit` and `exit` declares the parameter as *[ optional ]*, which is also apparent from its examples. I admit it could be a little clearer, but it *is* shown.

Comment: @deceze thanks for pointing that out. In practise, it does work perfectly well without the param - I was just looking for some confirmation I was using the function properly.

Comment: `die` does not officially **require** a message parameter, but it can take one optionally, as pointed out above. Your titular question is "must you" use the parameter: so, trivially, your answer is (2). However, you are implicitly asking (since you already know it works both ways) if it's better practice to use the optional parameter: best practices of this nature are by definition opinion based.

Comment: My question is very explicit actually. _Must I_ is loosely a synonym for _Am I required to_. Regarding me already knowing it works both ways - I wasn't **sure** it worked both ways, even though in the past it **seemed** to work both ways. As you can see, I wasn't asking for 'best practices'.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the official manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php) `die` is equivalent to `exit`, and `exit` [does not require an argument](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php).

Also, I think lots of people feel that w3schools is not a good source of solid information. ([Why?](http://www.w3fools.com/))

And also, exceptions are better (generally, depending of course on what you're doing).

Comment: I think for a time w3schools did not update their information/tutorials, even when issues were pointed out, and thus became unreliable.  [w3fools](http://www.w3fools.com/) was put up by a bunch of fairly high profile people pointing this out.  I'm not sure if they are better now, but personally avoid it.

Comment: And for php resources, I think [phptherightway](http://www.phptherightway.com/) is better.

Answer (score -1):

In PHP missing parameters are replaced by `null` - and since `null` has a printable string representation (the empty string), it is perfectly legal, while not elegant, to use `die();`

Comment: *If* a function *requires* a parameter, it *requires* a parameter. A missing parameter will not implicitly be substituted by `null`, and what the function itself would do with `null` also depends entirely on the function.

Comment: @henrywright Eugen's explanation is not really correct. `die` is an alias of `exit`, and both do not require parameters. W3S is wrong, as is often the case.

Comment: @deceze But `die()` doesn't require a parameter - the parameter is optional, so it is `null` if not given ... please elaborate!

Comment: If the parameter is not given it is not given. It is not `null`, it is *not given*. If a parameter is *optional* its internal default value may be any value, not necessarily `null`.

Comment: The way I'm understanding what you're writing is that `die` *does* require a parameter, but if you don't give it one PHP will implicitly pass a `null` which happens to cast to an empty string which happens to satisfy the requirement for a parameter. And that's simply no true.

Comment: Whatever. Let's agree to disagree.